# mvc recuperar datos desde vista y refrescar

Tags: c#, .net, mvc

Tengo una sola vista en mi proyecto, de la cual el usuario tiene que introducir un nombre de cliente para buscarlo en un buzon de correo.

```
<form action="registrarCliente" method="post">

<input id="textCliente" name="textCliente" /> <input id="btnAdd" 
type="submit" value="Añadir" />
</form>
<form action="eliminarCliente" method="post">

<input id="textCliente" name="textCliente" /> <input id="btnDel" 
type="submit" value="Eliminar" />
</form>
```

De esta manera recupero los datos de la vista, pero a la hora de pasarlo al controlador, este me abre otra dirección url con una vista que no existe.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult registrarCliente(String nombre, String textCliente) 
    {

        CorreosServices correosServices = new CorreosServices();

        correosServices.añadirCliente(textCliente);

        return View("/home/index");

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult eliminarCliente(String nombre, String textCliente)
    {

        CorreosServices correosServices = new CorreosServices();

        correosServices.eliminarCliente(textCliente);

        return View("/home/index");

    }
```

Querria que me refrescarla la pagina de /home/index, en vez de devolverme la url /registrarCliente o /eliminarCliente, que no existen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar tendrías que corregir el error que tienes en los atributos de las acciones. En las acciones especificas el atributo `HttpGet` (responderán a las llamadas realizadas con el método GET), mientras que en el formulario especificas que utilice el método POST (`method="post"`) con lo que tu código no se ejecutará nunca.

Modifica tu código para establecer el atributo `[HttpPost]` en tus acciones.

Para devolver la vista correspondiente a `Home/Index` tienes varias alternativas:

Si las acciones `registrarCliente` y `eliminarCliente` están en el mismo controlador te bastará con llamar al método `View` con el nombre de la vista:

```
return View("Index");
```

Si están en otro controlador podrías optar por mover la vista `Index` a la carpeta `Shared` y llamarla igual (únicamente con el nombre) o especificar la ruta completa de la vista:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Otra opción es realizar una redirección a la acción `Home/Index` con lo que además se ejecutará el código definido en esta acción (que en los casos anteriores no se ejecutaría):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: Gracias, pero la  Index necesita un modelo para ejecutarse, como a demas de     return View("Index"); paso tambien el modelo?

Comment: Si necesita un modelo deberás generarlo en la acción y pasárselo en el método `View` (ej: `return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", modeloObj);`), o utilizar la opción de redireccionar a la acción de la home y dejar que esa acción genere el modelo. Por eso te especificaba que únicamente en este último paso se ejecuta el código de la acción `Home/Index`.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, no termine de caer...